# covering more test after python coding to include exception scenario

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

say

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
except requests.ConnectionError, e:
    print(e)
```

how do i use pytest to test the lines from 'except'? That is when there is an error while trying to get/post?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to capture the code's standard output (which is the file that `print` writes to). You can do this using the `capsys` fixture.

```
def test_code(capsys):
    # Code in which the request will fail
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)

    assert capsys.readouterr().out == "Expected error message"
```